# Android Maps - Is there a way to check if there are tolls in a route?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I am building an app that I use matrix google api to get distance, time and I see that I can use it to avoid tolls. But I would like to know if there is a way to check if there are tolls or not in the route I have traced between two coordinates points on the google maps.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

By now it is not possible by google maps but I was able to do that with https://www.tollsmart.com/, you need to choose a plan according to your demand.